# How do import sample-data before setup new site magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, sample-data

i tried setup  magento2-1.0.0-beta branch Develop but get error relate to installing data. So i want import sample-data before setup new site magento2. How do it ?

Answer (score -1):

First you need to take Backup of Magento whole database, from existing magento version. By importing through phpmyadmin->Database_name-> And then select Export->Then Go.